# VS 2020 No access to TableLayoutPanel control in WinForm's C# code view

Tags: c#, user-controls, visual-studio-2022, designer, tablelayoutpanel

I have been struggling with this problem all week. I read many posts here but none solved the problem.

The issue I’m having is with a program that is made up of two projects: a WinForm and a UserControl written in C# in the VS2022 environment.

The WinForm contains a TableLayoutPanel control. Each cell of the TableLayoutPanel is populated with a control from my UserControl project. The VS designer displays all this correctly.

When I build the UserControl project there are no errors.
When I build the WinForm project (i.e frmSudokuProbe) I get the following errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdgZj.png)

It says that there is no definition for tableLayoutPanel1 in the WinForm project but the designer code shows that tableLayoutPanel1 is defined:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JQ8g.png)

The WinForm project fails when it refers to tableLayoutPanel1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J92EH.png)

I rely on the VS designer to make the tableLayoutPanel1 control visible to the WinForm project on which it is displayed. But for some reason that control and only that control is not defined.
This was not an issue until I upgraded to VS2022. I tried different combinations of target platforms on each project, including “AnyCpu” and “x86”. I tried different framework versions. I even reinstalled VS2019 with no success. Is there something I need to do? Is there a work around?

I'm looking for a clean compile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did the actual DECLARATION of the TableLayoutPanel somehow get deleted? It should be in the designer file near the top: `private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;`

Comment: @Idle_Mind - It appears that the designer deletes that line.If I add that line to the designer code, the program compiles but fails when it reaches any code referencing tableLayoutPanel1.

Comment: Yeah, basically your designer file is "corrupt", meaning VS somehow managed to put it into a state where it is confused and not finding things where it expects them to be. Sometimes I've found there is no way to "fix" this  kind of issue except to rebuild that Form from scratch, wiring up the event handlers, and then copying the code over from the old Form.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - Thanks. I was afraid of that because this is a complex form.

Comment: When I compare the designer code to a comparable solution, the problem solution has the following:  this.components = new                       System.ComponentModel.Container(); System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1; at the beginning of the definition. The comparable solution that works does not. The problem solution is missing the line : private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;  The comparable solution is not.